# Apply select2 to a dialog element in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, widget, ckeditor

can i use a javascript plugin in a dialog element in `ckeditor`?

I want to implement `select2` plugin on a dialog select element in a widget i am building.

i used

```
   /* plugin.js */

     editor.on('instanceReady',function () {
     CKEDITOR.document.appendStyleSheet(plugin.path + select2/select2.css");
     });

     CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(js.select2);

/* element definition in dialog.js */
 {
  id: 'objectId',
  type: 'select',
  label: 'Object Name',
  items: [['Select', '-1']....],
  onLoad: function (widget) {
          var selectbx = $('#' + selectList.getInputElement().id);
          selectbx.select2();

                     },
```

if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Calling select2() on onLoad() works fine. The only issue is that the dropdown is squished and the list opens somewhere behind the dialog box.
I have worked around this with a little bit of CSS to fix the z-index of the dropdown and the width of the CKEditor select:

```
div.cke_dialog_ui_input_select,
.cke_dialog_ui_input_select{
    width: 100%;
}

.select2-drop{
    z-index: 100000;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `select2 4.x` this css worked for me"

div.cke_dialog_ui_input_select,

```
.cke_dialog_ui_input_select {
  width: 100%;
}

.select2-container {
  z-index: 10010;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  position: relative;
}
```